# keep track of multiple terminals from shell script

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, scripts

I am writing a quick start shell script to automatically set up my development environment for a current project. However, none of the commands in the shell script can be executed after my server starts because it takes over the terminal. I am trying to open a new tab, start the server in there and then continue executing my shell script in the original tab. My script currently looks like this:

```
subl myProj
cd myProj
gnome-terminal --tab
npm start
google-chrome http://localhost:3000
```

myProj ends up opening in the new tab and the server starts in the original tab. chrome never launches.

Comment: Adding to Serg's answer: you probably want those programs to not be bounded to the terminal. Look into `bash`'s `disown` built-in (to be used in conjunction with `&`) an into the `nohup` command

Comment: i'll take a look at those, but if they make the server run as a daemon and free up the terminal, it's not what i'm looking for. This is for my dev envrionment and I need the output I get from the server in the terminal.

Comment: Well using `&` to put the process into the background also inhibits `stdout` / `stderr`, so you probably want to start the server at the end of the script. If not possible however you may still start it where you need it to start backgrounding it with `&`, start everything else with `&` + `disown`/ `nohup` and then put it into the foreground again using the `fg` built-in

Comment: @kos can you elaborate on how it inhibits stdout / stderr ? I just tried a few operations and the output seems normal. Does it only inhibit output under certain conditions?

Comment: I guess it does. Then it must be program-dependent. `watch -n 1 echo foo &`, for one, suppresses output. Not sure about what this depends on tough.

Comment: Yes, it does output stderr only when there's an actual error. You could always add redirection if you didn't want any text output to the command line

Comment: @Serg Can you explain this? Try `cat /dev/urandom &` (and be ready to close it by other mean than Ctrl+C). Then try `watch -n 1 echo foo &`. Do you have any idea why the output is not suppressed in `cat` but it is in `watch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts execute commands in sequence, and wait until each command finishes. However, there is a way to allow the script to continue executing past a specific command - add `&` on the end of the script.

For instance:

```bsh
!#/bin/bash
firefox
echo "Next line"
```

Will wait till firefox is closed.

```bsh
!#/bin/bash
firefox &
echo "Next line"
```

Will execute `echo` command and allow keeping firefox open

Comment: Short and precise =)